# Connect multiple android devices to a "main" pc app

Tags: java, android

I want to create and run an application (in java) in a computer and allow multiple users to use their android devices as input devices to that main app. It must be in real time for every device.

For example: To do some follow up exercises after a training session. Users would register them selves (a simple form that would send strings to the main app on the PC) then they get some questions and every question as a timer, so who answers correctly and faster gets a better grade.

What's the best way to get this done? And yes, if it makes it easier, the connections can be through internet/LAN.

Comment: the kind of application you are looking would involve client server communication where your mobile devices would be clients and you can setup a server to communicate. its easy to setup but not as easy the way you are describing.

Comment: I see... so i would have to create a server (the PC running the main app) then the android devices would connect to that sever IP and specific port to communicate. Using sockets. Looks simple if its like that :) At least in normal (none android) java apps i can work with sockets... i didn't work with sockets on android but ill search that. Thx

Comment: The client/server model seems to fit.  In fact, leaving aside handing out the address of the server in a convenient way (something the local DNS may be able to fix), you could probably do this using just the device browser and a fairly ordinary web server (an advantage being easy multi-platform support)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there are two parts to this. The first is a database system to handle user registration etc... look into SQL for that. There are many approaches. In terms of getting multiple phones connected to a computer PC you will need a server that can handle threads and a client for the phone.

A server needs server sockets. Server sockets can accept more than one connected client at a time. A threaded server might look like this:

```
public class ServerThread extends Thread
{
    //is the thread running
    private boolean running = true;

    //ports for the server sockets
    private final int dataPort;
    private final int filePort;

    private final String certificateDir;
    private final char[] password;

    private Vector<ClientHandlerThread> connectedClients = new Vector<ClientHandlerThread>(20, 5);
    private Properties userProperties = new Properties();

    public ServerThread(int dataPort,
                        int filePort,
                        String certificateDir,
                        char[] password,
                        Properties userProperties)
    {
        this.dataPort = dataPort;
        this.filePort = filePort;
        this.certificateDir = certificateDir;
        this.password = password;
        this.userProperties = userProperties;
    }

    public void run()
    {
        /*
         * We need a server socket that can accept traffic. I use one for file traffic and one
         * for data traffic although one socket could be used.
         */
        SSLServerSocket sslDataTraffic = null;
        SSLServerSocket sslFileTraffic = null;
        SSLServerSocketFactory sslFac = null;

        /*
         * Everything in the following block is related to creating a SSL security manager. 
         * If you don't need validated communications you don't have to use SSL. Just normal
         * sockets.
         */
        try
        {
            KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
            keyStore.load(new FileInputStream(certificateDir), password);

            TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
            tmf.init(keyStore);

            KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance((KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm()));
            kmf.init(keyStore, password);

            System.setProperty("https.protocols", "SSL");
            SSLContext ctx = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
            ctx.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(), tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);
            sslFac = ctx.getServerSocketFactory();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("FAILED.");
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(-1);
        }

        try
        {
            //create data server socket 
            System.out.print("Creating data socket......... ");
            sslDataTraffic = (SSLServerSocket) sslFac.createServerSocket(dataPort);
            System.out.println("DONE. Est. on:" + dataPort);

            //create file server socket
            System.out.print("Creating file socket......... ");
            sslFileTraffic = (SSLServerSocket) sslFac.createServerSocket(filePort);
            System.out.println("DONE. Est. on:" + filePort);
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            System.out.println("FAILED.");
            System.out.println(e.toString() + " ::: " + e.getCause());
            System.exit(-1);
        }

        /*
         * This block is used to print the ip the server is running on. Easy to incorporate this here
         * so the information doesn't have to be gathered form another source.
         */
        try
        {
            System.out.print("Finishing.................... ");
            Socket s = new Socket("google.com", 80);
            System.out.println("DONE.");
            System.out.println("Server online at: " + s.getLocalAddress().getHostAddress());
            System.out.println("====================*====================");
            s.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        /*
         * This is the block that accepts connections from clients.
         */
        try
        {
            while (running)
            {
                //wait here until a connection is bound to new sockets through the server sockets
                SSLSocket sslDataTrafficSocketInstance = (SSLSocket) sslDataTraffic.accept();
                SSLSocket sslFileTrafficSocketInstance = (SSLSocket) sslFileTraffic.accept();
                //sockets to communicate with the client are created. Lets put them in a thread so 
                //we can continue to accept new clients while we work with the newly and previously
                //connected clients

                //create a new thread
                ClientHandlerThread c = new ClientHandlerThread(
                        sslDataTrafficSocketInstance, 
                        sslFileTrafficSocketInstance, 
                        userProperties);
                //start thread
                c.start();
                //add newly connected client to the list of connected clients
                connectedClients.add(c);
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Fatal server error, terminating server and client handler threads");

            stopServer();
        }
    }
}
```

The constructor of the ClientHandlerThread class looks like this:

```
    private PrintWriter writer;
    private BufferedReader reader;
    private InputStream inputStream;
    private OutputStream outputStream;

    public ClientHandlerThread(
            SSLSocket dataSocket,
            SSLSocket fileSocket,
            Properties userProperties)
    {
        this.dataSocket = dataSocket;
        this.fileSocket = fileSocket;

        this.userProperties = userProperties;

        try
        {
            this.reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.dataSocket.getInputStream()));
            this.writer = new PrintWriter(this.dataSocket.getOutputStream());
            this.inputStream = fileSocket.getInputStream();
            this.outputStream = fileSocket.getOutputStream();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Notice streams are created from the sockets. This is what opens the communication channel to the client. The thread can send a receive data and requests. What requests you write and the way you handle them is up to you.

The client will look very similar to the server but with one big difference. The client needs to initialize the handshake. One side must send data first to initialize the communication. Since the client is connecting to the server I typically have the client send the first set of data. The client's connection code might look like this method:

```
    private void connect()
    {
        try
        {
            SSLSocketFactory sslFac;
            SSLSocket dataSocket = null;
            SSLSocket fileSocket = null;

            /*
             * This block is nearly identical to the security block for the server side.  
             */
            try
            {
                KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
                keyStore.load(new FileInputStream(certificateDir), password.toCharArray());

                TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
                tmf.init(keyStore);

                KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance((KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm()));
                kmf.init(keyStore, password.toCharArray());

                System.setProperty("https.protocols", "SSL");
                SSLContext ctx = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
                ctx.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(), tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);
                sslFac = ctx.getSocketFactory();

                String ip = "<THE SERVER'S IP ADDRESS>";
                dataSocket = (SSLSocket) sslFac.createSocket(ip, dataPort);
                fileSocket = (SSLSocket) sslFac.createSocket(ip, filePort);
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                System.out.println("FAILED.");
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.exit(-1);
            }

            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(dataSocket.getInputStream()));
            writer = new PrintWriter(dataSocket.getOutputStream());
            OutputStream fileOut = fileSocket.getOutputStream();

            writer.println("CLIENT_HANDSHAKE_INIT");
            writer.flush();
            }
     }
```

At this point you should have a client connected to a server and the client should have initialized the handshake. You have streams open to each other on both ends allowing the server and client to communicate. At this point you can begin polishing and building up the server and client to do what you actually want to do. The code I've provided is missing a dew parts that you will need to fill in as you tailor the system to your specific needs. I provided this system as an example for you to follow. **A few notes. Remember someone has to start the handshake for communication to take place. Remember the streams must be flushed for the data to transmit. This security model does not apply to public connections.** I was strictly trying to prevent outside connections from being successful. You will need to do more research on SSL if you need secured connections.

Hope this gave you some ideas about the server-client model and what you want to do with it.

Cheers,

Will

Comment: UPDATE: I posted this a while ago, and have since needed to make a more efficient model. I will not post the code here because it is long, but I advise anyone who stumbles across this question to look at SocketChannels. They are a part of nio and are much more efficient than the one-thread-per-connected-client model.